# Usage of marker decorators in my own view

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I want to use the decorators, which are used for the problem markers in the Project Explorer, in my own view.

I got a solution with my own decorator using:

```
ILabelDecorator decorator = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDecoratorManager().getLabelDecorator();
viewer.setLabelProvider(new DecoratingLabelProvider(new ViewLabelProvider(), decorator));
```

But I hope there is a better way to decorate the IResource in my view. I don't use e4.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

At the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGSJh.jpg) you can see the seams.bib file in the project explorer and my own view. the file is decorated with a warning triangle and a light bulb in the project explorer and with a lightbulb only in my view.
Both decorators depend on the marker shown in the problem view. I want to display the warning triangle (which is an eclipse internal decorator) instead of the lightbulb in my view.

Comment: That is the usual way to use decorators. What is the problem with it?

Comment: The problem for me is that I have to implement new decorators when their implementation already exists and this causes the resources in the project explorer to be decorated twice.

Comment: Not sure I understand. You can control which decorations are shown in the Preferences in 'General > Appearance > Label Decorations'.